# How to fill a function pointer member with class instance member function pointer?

Tags: c++, c, function, interface, function-pointers

Having a C API I need to create a C++ object that extends it like so:

```
struct OldCInterface {
   void (*doStuff)();
};

struct NewCXXBaseClass : protected OldCInterface {
   virtual void doStuff(); 
   virtual ~NewCXXBaseClass();
};
```

How to put instance pointer to CXX doStuff into C interface in the constructor if possible having it pointing to overload if we have Base child?

Answer (score 2):

`void (*doStuff)()` if a function pointer, while `&NewCXXBaseClass::doStuff` is of type `void (NewCXXBaseClass::*)()`, that is, pointer to member function. They are not compatible. Usually, they are not even of the same size (`sizeof(void (*)()) != sizeof(void (NewCXXBaseClass::*)())`). Saying so, the following is correct

```
struct OldCInterface {
   void (NewCXXBaseClass::*doStuff)();
};
```

But since your original intention is to work with some old C code. This probably does not work. Your best best is to make a static member function that calls into the virtual member function of some object. An illustration:

```
struct Proxy {
  static NewCXXBaseClass* s_p_;
  static void DoStuff() {
    s_p_->DoStuff();
  }
};
```

`&Proxy::DoStuff` is of type `void(*)()` and can be used where a function pointer is expected. Then, you can do the following:

`OldCInterface c_interface = {&Proxy::DoStuff};`